# how to write one string at time using qtcpsocket?

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

How to send string using Qtcpsocket, when using

```
tcpsocket->write("hello");

tcpsocket->write("world");

etc..

tcpSocket->flush();
tcpSocket->waitForBytesWritten(3000);
```

it send it in one string "hello world", what i want make it write only one at time, i want make client recive  "hello" then "world".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not how TCP works.  TCP is a byte stream protocol, not a message protocol.  You might programatically write N bytes on the sending side, but the remote end might not receive all N bytes at once.  In fact, when it does a `recv` on its end, it might only get 1 byte, N-1 bytes, or some other number of bytes.  Issues such as IP fragmentation, TCP segmentation, TCP window size, can influence this.

Further if you write "Hello" and "World" separately to the socket, the message could easily get coalesced (on the sender or receiver side), such that "HelloWorld" is received all at once.  Again, because TCP is a byte stream, not a message based protocol.

When you write TCP code, you have to deal with these issues, because they really do happen.

When you want to do:

Each word is a "message".  But each message needs it's only encapsulation.  Perhaps you could send the messages like this:

```
 tcpsocket->write("hello|");
 tcpsocket->write("world|");
```

Where the trailing `|` pipe character of each word is the delimiter between each logical word.  You could also use a space instead of a pipe char.  Or have your own protocol header to indicate the number of bytes to follow.  Regardless, it's up to the receiving side to parse the the messages from the byte stream back together to form the application messages.